# Corrupt project? All the layers are blue

Tags: qgis, layers, symbology, corrupt

I opened my QGIS project which I often work on and all the layers were blue.
Something like that never happened to me before. I'm not sure what could've caused something like this. It's as if QGIS forgot all the symbologies and attributed blue to all of them.

Does anybody know a quick fix to this?

I'm using QGIS Desktop 3.16.6[image]

Comment: Have you tried reloading an older version?

Comment: It is likely because you have opened the project in an older version of QGIS than in which it was saved.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this:

1. Check if you install a newer version of QGIS
2. Right click on the project --> open with --> navigate to  C:\Program Files

- --> Select the older version of QGIS (ie: C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.1)
- --> Then navigate to bin subfolder and select qgis-bin.exe

It works for me.